# Why is the first Rails request extremely slow in testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

In Ruby on Rails, when I run the rails server, the very first request seems to be extremely slow, the logs show that the slowness comes from the view rendering:

```
2017-08-14 10:24:12.707 [ 22139] [INFO ] Completed 200 OK in 18547ms (Views: 18501.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
```

I assume it's because it needs to connect to the database. The next request is of course, fast(er):

```
2017-08-14 11:01:54.937 [ 25662] [INFO ] Completed 200 OK in 765ms (Views: 714.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
```

I assume this has something to do with the cache, and it already has a database connection. I've tried to restart my server, restart the database, clear my browser cache and `rake db:sessions:clear`, but I am unable to get the first request to go slow again in development.

Here's where things get interesting. *Every single time* I run the cucumber tests, the very first request is always incredibly slow:

```
2017-08-14 11:19:52.879 [ 27729] [INFO ] Completed 200 OK in 38326ms (Views: 38306.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
```

It's even longer than it is in development for unknown reasons.

**What is different between restarting the Rails server and re-running a test that makes the first request of the tests so slow? What steps can I take to troubleshoot such an issue?**

(It's no fun waiting 30 seconds every time we want to run one of our cucumber tests)

Comment: are you using spring? (or something like it?)

Comment: Not at this time, that has caused issues in the past when we didn't realize we needed to restart the spring server for odd issues

Comment: i'm not sure we know enough about your set up to be much help... is it still slow, if you just run one do-nothing test (like true == true) all by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer was extremely isolated to our code, but I wanted to share the answer in-case anyone else ever ran into this situation.

I noticed that if I ran `rake tmp:cache:clear` the first request in the browser would be really slow again. I investigated that command and saw it cleared out the `#{Rails.root}/tmp` directory.

I then found this line in the Cucumber `env.rb`:

```
Dir.foreach("#{Rails.root}/tmp") { |f|
  FileUtils.rm_rf("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{f}")
}
```

That appeared to be the culprit the entire time. I don't know why that was added (3 years ago...)